# how to pull values from PHP JSON with jQuery JSON?

Tags: php, jquery, json

Ok here is the thing I got PHP to encode some MySQL information into JSON format and then force jQuery to get this via a file located on my server. The PHP generated JSON encode looks like this, the problem is I do not understand how would I go about pulling file, size, name, preview from the JSON array with use of jQuery

Here is a sample JSON array

```
[{"aid":"416","type":"image\/jpeg","size":"1826611","file":"http:\/\/*****.com\/aws-eu\/-f\/Cat.jpg","user_id":"0","token":"b5bb0380c6912cd3464747b9f29355e7","name":"Cat.jpg","qp_tag":"1f3a4e30x","preview":"aws-eu\/-t\/sample_Cat.jpg","oath":"b5bb0380c6912cd3464747b9f29355e7"},
```

Could someone help me out with pulling information from it to jQuery and displaying it in a DIV afterwords

Comment: I'd just like to clarify that JSON is JSON, no matter where is was encoded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON in JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464188/json-in-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

[`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is what you want.

```
$.getJSON('path/to/file.json', function(response) {
   $('div#something').text(response[0].file);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a callback to `getJSON` so that you can read the JSON's data after it's been retrieved from the PHP file's URL. The JSON data is returned as the parameter to the callback:

```
$.getJSON('yourphpfile.php', function(data){
    // Here data[0].size === "1826611"
});
```

Since your JSON data is seems to be an array, you can access the first items of the array by doing `data[0]`. You can access any property of that item by using its name, e.g. `data[0].size`.