# Json with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I just want to know how to get the json data in phtml file. Below is my php controller.

```
foreach($result AS $row) {  
    $arrValues[] = array("firstname"=>$row['firstname'], 
                         "emailid"=>$row['emailid'],
                         "lastname"=>$row['lastname']); 
}
header("Content-type: application/json", true);             
echo json_encode(array('rows'=>$arrValues));
```

This is my phtml file.

```
var emailid=$(this).data('emailid');   

//alert(emailid);  

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/feedback/public/index/email/',
    type: 'POST',                                    
    data: {emaildata: emailid }, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) { 
        var emailid = data[0];              
        var vname = data[1];
        var vlaname=data[2];
        var w = window.open('', 'Feedback', 'width=400,height=400,resizeable,scrollbars');
        w.document.write("FirstName"+data[0]);
    }
});
```

Im trying to write those values in apop up window.But it says object.Could you please help me how to get the json data and write that in to popwindow.

Comment: Can you access the data in JavaScript as such?  w.document.write("FirstName"+data['firstname'])

Comment: But it says like undefined..thanks for the replu

Comment: That's because the default string representation of objects is `[object Object]`. Access the properties of the objects to get the actual values. If you don't know how, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects. Also, when you post code and you expect us to read it, please format it properly.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464188/json-in-jquery.

Comment: @cds Consider `console.log(data)` to help decipher what is being returned from the `json` request.

Answer (score 2):

```
success: function(data) { 
    var emailid = data.rows[0].emailid;              
    var vname = data.rows[0].firstname;
    var vlaname=data.rows[0].lastname;
    var w = window.open('', 'Feedback', 'width=400,height=400,resizeable,scrollbars');
    w.document.write("FirstName"+data.rows[0].firstname);
}
```